# How can I namespace a SystemJS bundle

Tags: javascript, namespaces, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I am building a bundle using the SystemJS builder that I'd like to include in another project. The problem I'm running into is that bundle A and bundle B might both contain a 'main' module, and when I bundle them and include them in another project, they collide and everything breaks.

Does SystemJS builder have a better way of namespacing? Or from preventing bundled modules from being exported at all? Or is there another tool I should be using?

Comment: I would think that's a clue there's a design issue. In my opinion, bundles that aren't "app bundles" should not have main module, and app bundles should not be co-loaded with each other.

Comment: main was an example dude, its possible to have other name collisions.

Comment: Shouldn't `a/main` and `b/main` already be different modules? Unless you are using global module identifiers, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: they are being developed separately. module a is a project and module b is a project, and they are built and included in the parent app. so when i build and include them using system js, both modulea.built.js and moduleb.built.js have things like `system.register("main")`

Answer (score 1):

SystemJS does not have an easy way to do what you want.

You could import the module by path instead of by name.

```
import x1 from "folder1/x.js"
import x2 from "folder2/x.js"
```

You could also try to have two instances of SystemJS.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30954312/6101582

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/982

You could also rename the modules.